# Select all completed months until certain date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns certain time series information. But since I am doing analysis for each completed month, I would like to ignore the last month information so it does not contaminate the data. So the actual data would look similar to this:

```
       T.Date          T.Profit
     1/1/2016          15
     1/15/2016         25
     1/29/2016          5
     2/03/2016          10
```

So, I was thinking in doing something like:

where `T.Date <= Datefromparts(Year(max(T.Date)),Month(Max(T.Date)),1)`

And I would receive something like:

```
       T.Date          T.Profit
     1/1/2016          15
     1/15/2016         25
     1/29/2016          5
```

But seems like this is not the way.

Comment: And how do you know that a month is "completed"?  Your attempt and all the suggestions are based on the "last" row, not on any definition of "completed". A tiny set of sample data may lead you to invalid assumptions and incorrect logic.

Comment: Well... If you always substract the last month, you will always have completed months... For example:

Let's say last date(LD)(MM/DD/YYYY) is 1/02/2019. In this case, we will remove all 01 and we would have completed dates,

Scenario 2: LD= 01/31/2019. This would be our worst scenario, since it would remove a completed month, but still, it is better to remove a completed month and have a few less data, than contaminate the data each time you create a pull... with probabilities of 29/30 or 30/31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your approach:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(date) over () as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where t.date < datefromparts(year(max_date), month(max_date), 1);
```

Perhaps more colloquially, this could be written as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date < (select dateadd(day, 1 - day(max(date)), max(date))
                from t
               );
```

Comment: Even though I knew the logic, since I am new to SQL I had wrong the syntax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to select only the month that you need to analyze

```
select * from Datefromparts where MONTH([T.Date]) != MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR([T.Date]) = 2016
```

Also if you want you can get all the previous months with this

```
select * from Datefromparts where MONTH([T.Date]) < MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR([T.Date]) = 2016
```

Comment: In this example it was only 1 month, but I was assuming there would be N previous months. Sorry for not being clear